# Code First EF on Local DB - Moving to Enterprise SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I initially developed my application's data model as Code First EF6 using LocalDB and all has been working fine.

I now need to move the DB to our Enterprise SQL Server environment but I do not have the appropriate permissions to be able to use Code First... All scripts to create/modify have to be generated, evaluated, approved and executed by the DBAs..

The problem I have is that I am having issues with my DB Connect string as the ones I've tried have failed. As said, before I was using LocalDB and the default connect string was used.

**DBContext Constructor**

```
public HotelRequestDBContext() : base("HotelRequestsDB")
{
    //Database.SetInitializer<HotelRequestDBContext>(new HotelRequestDBContextInitialiser());

    if (Properties.Settings.Default.EFTrace)
    {
        this.Database.Log = msg => System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(msg);
    }

}
```

**Connection String Attempt 1**

```
<add name="HotelRequestsDB" connectionString="Data Source=server\instance;initial catalog=HoteRequests;persist security info=True;user id=username;password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

`Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in EntityFramework.dll`

`Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'data source'.`

`If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.`

**Connection String Attempt 2**

```
<add name="HoteRequestsDB" connectionString="metadata=res://*/HoteRequests.csdl|res://*/HoteRequests.ssdl|res://*/HoteRequests.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=server\instance;initial catalog=HoteRequests;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

*Exception pop-up window*

`Exception thrown: 'System.Data.DataException' in EntityFramework.dll`

`Additional information: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.`

`If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.`

*Debug Output Window*

`Cannot attach the file 'C:\Projects\HotelRequests\HotelRequests\App_Data\HotelRequestsDB.mdf' as database 'HotelRequestsDB'.`

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Just to be clear, the database is already on the sql server? as you said you can't use code first to create them yourself

Comment: Yes... the database (and entities) have been created on the enterprise SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end of your connectionstring `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"` is what's causing this normally. Somewhere in the config file of your startup project, you should see some xml with the `<entityFramework>` tag. It is automatically generated.

To connect to a sql-server you need to make sure the `<provider>` is the following:

```
<entityFramework>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.EntityClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

(You should change the name to `System.Data.SqlClient` too, both in your connectionstring and providername to be correct.)

Comment: Well, apart from the fact that I had the "Initial Catalog" name incorrect, changing the "provider" on the end of the connect string entry resolved the issue... Thanks

Comment: ah yeah, you forgot an 'l' gotta love typos ;)